# Cast AnnotatedElement to a class type

Tags: java, reflection

i wanted to know how i can improve the current code or if there is a more effective/cleaner way to cast the AnnotatedElement return to a class type instead of making a method for every type ex asClass, asMethod, etc...

```
protected AnnotatedElement create() {
    if (type == Type.CLASS) {
        return new ClassFinder(name).get(); // Return Class
    } else if (type == Type.CONSTRUCTOR) {
        return new ConstructorFinder(name).get(); // Return Constructor
    } else if (type == Type.METHOD) {
        return new MethodFinder(name).get(); // Return Method
    }  else {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}


public Class<?> asClass() {
    return (Class<?>) create();
}

public Constructor asConstructor() {
    return (Constructor) create();
}

public Method asMethod() {
    return (Method) create();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to _do_ with it?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568933/convert-annotatedelement-to-its-class-type

Comment: Just get rid of the `create()` method. `public Class<?> asClass() { return new ClassFinder(name).get(); }`, `public Constructor asConstructor() { return new ConstructorFinder(name).get(); }`, `public Method asMethod() { return new MethodFinder(name).get(); }`